# Перестали работать flash сообщения, после добавления Ajax

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails

Перестали работать flash сообщения, после того как добавил Ajax для создания и удаления комментария. В чем может быть дело?

```
    class CommentsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = @post.comments.create(comment_params)
    @comment.user_id = current_user.id
    if @comment.save
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html do
          flash[:success] = "Your comment has been posted."
          redirect_to @post
        end
        format.js
      end
    else
      flash.now[:danger] = "error"
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { render @post }
        format.js
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
    @comment.destroy


    respond_to do |format|
      format.html do
        flash[:success] = "Comment deleted."
        redirect_to post_path(@post)
      end
      format.js
    end
  end


  private
    def comment_params
      params.require(:comment).permit(:user_id, :content)
    end
end
```

create.js.erb:

```
$('#comments-list').append('<%= escape_javascript(render @comment) %>');
$("#commentCount").html("Comments(<%= @post.comments.count %>)");
```

destroy.js.erb:

```
$("#comments-list").html("<%= escape_javascript(render @post.comments) %>");
$("#commentCount").html("Comments(<%= @post.comments.count %>)");
```

Весь код проекта: https://bitbucket.org/Tiazar/callboard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну так ты никак их не отдаёшь на форму.

1.
Ты делаешь `flash[:success] = "Comment deleted."` только если собираешься рендерить html. Видимо правильнее вынести эту строчку из `respond_to`.

2.
У тебя в `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb` есть код:

```
<% flash.each do |key, value| %>
  <div class="alert alert-<%= key %>">
    <%= value %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Именно он и отображает эти сообщения при рендеринге страницы. В случае если ты отдаёшь ответ в аяксом то этот код не участвует в рендеринге.
Тебе нужно вынести этот кусок кода например в `app/views/layouts/_flash.html.erb`
Затем в `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb` вместо него сделать:

```
<div class="JS-headers">
  <%= render 'layouts/flash' %>
</div>
```

И в свой js-представления добавить строку:

```
$(".JS-headers").html("<%=j render 'layouts/flash' %>");
```

Comment: Должен ли пункт 2 работать без п1? Все вместе работает замечательно, спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Нет конечно. п.2 обеспечивает вывод. П.1 - формирование сообщения. Поотдельности либо нечему выводить их либо некуда.